# How do I fix Internet Explorer / Firefox differences in Oracle JD Edwards Enterprise?

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer-7

Our company uses Oracle's JD Edwards Enterprise to do accounting work.  We have an application consultant working for us to just deal JD Edwards but he is of non-technical background so only helps in application-specific support.

All of our users should use IE 7 for JDE.  About 15-20% of those users have problems which cause them to not be able to use IE 7.  So those problematic users use firefox.  For the most part firefox works fine but there are a few issues.  Some menus / options within JDE that are present in IE 7 are not present in firefox.

If I could get all of our users working under IE 7, all the firefox issues would be mute points.  I have cross referenced Internet Options settings from a working IE 7 user and a non-working IE 7 user.  All settings seem to be mirrored.

I'm not sure how to go about continuing to troubleshoot this issue.  So not only answers but just suggestive ideas for attack would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does JDEE mention officialy supported browsers? IE 7 only? IE, firfox? If they only list certain ones, that might be your only supported option and one would expect possible issues with other browsers.

Comment: If you are having issues with supported configurations, you might want to contact the software company directly and get some support.

Answer (score 1):

I have one client who uses this software and there is no *real* solution you can do. Simply put, they have used IE specific markup and Firefox just cannot render it.

If you have a problem with IE as a program but not the engine, you may have some luck trying the Firefox addin - [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419) which opens an Internet Explorer window with Firefox.

However, this is just a workaround and not a real fix. I would not recommend changing or editing the source files.

However, I suggest you post about the Internet Explorer problems separately as someone may be able to help you sort that out!